# awk/grep certain parts of a specific column

Tags: awk, grep

I have a question that I am at a loss to solve.
I have 3 column tab-separated data, such as:

```
abs nmod+n+n-commitment-n   349.200023
abs nmod+n+n-a-commitment-n 333.306429
abs into+ns-j+vn-pass-rb-divide-v   295.57316
abs nmod+n+ns-commitment-n  182.085018
abs nmod+n+n-pledge-n   149.927391
abs nmod+n+ns-reagent-n 142.347358
```

I need to isolate the last two "elements" of the third column, in which my desired result would be a 4-column output that only contains those elements that end with "-n".

such as:

```
abs nmod+n+n   commitment-n   349.200023
abs nmod+n+n-a   commitment-n 333.306429
abs nmod+n+ns   commitment-n  182.085018
abs nmod+n+n   pledge-n   149.927391
abs nmod+n+ns   reagent-n 142.347358
```

In this case, is there an `awk`, `grep` anything that can help? The files are approx. 500 MB, so they are not huge, but not small either.
Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this you can check if the 2nd column ends with `-n` and then print the lines:

```
$ awk '$2~/-n$/' file
abs nmod+n+n-commitment-n   349.200023
abs nmod+n+n-a-commitment-n 333.306429
abs nmod+n+ns-commitment-n  182.085018
abs nmod+n+n-pledge-n   149.927391
abs nmod+n+ns-reagent-n 142.347358
```

To have the second field splitted so that the last two elements are isolated, you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}
     $2~/-n$/ {
               size=split($2,a,"-");
               for (i=1; i<=size-2; i++) first=first"-"a[i];
               second=a[size-1]"-"a[size];
               print $1,first,second,$3;
               first=second=""
              }' file
```

which returns

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} $2~/-n$/ {size=split($2,a,"-"); for (i=1; i<=size-2; i++) first=first"-"a[i]; second=a[size-1]"-"a[size]; print $1,first,second,$3; first=second=""}' file
abs     -nmod+n+n       commitment-n    349.200023
abs     -nmod+n+n-a     commitment-n    333.306429
abs     -nmod+n+ns      commitment-n    182.085018
abs     -nmod+n+n       pledge-n        149.927391
abs     -nmod+n+ns      reagent-n       142.347358
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}` set tab as input an output field separator.
- `$2~/-n$/ {}` match lines in which the 2nd field ends with "-n" and do the things within `{}`.
- `size=split($2,a,"-")` cut the 2nd field in pieces based on the `-` delimiter and save them in the `a[]` array. Store the size of the array in `size` var.
- `for (i=1; i<=size-2; i++) first=first"-"a[i]; second=a[size-1]"-"a[size]` save the data in two different blocks: first everything up to the 2nd last field; then, the two last fields.
- `print $1,first,second,$3` print everything.
- `first=second=""` unset the variables.

Comment: +1 , yours is better, it seems that cannot avoid to use split(), I was lazy...:(  removed mine. but there are leading `-`s in 2nd col in your output. pls fix it.

Comment: finally found a way without splitting. :)

Comment: I knew you would find a way!! ;)

Answer (score 3):

give this one-liner a try: (gawk)

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$2~/-n$/{$2=gensub(/-([^-]*-n$)/,"\t\\1","g",$2);print}' file
```

output with your file (as `f`):

```
kent$  awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$2~/-n$/{$2=gensub(/-([^-]*-n$)/,"\t\\1","g",$2);print}' f
abs     nmod+n+n        commitment-n    349.200023
abs     nmod+n+n-a      commitment-n    333.306429
abs     nmod+n+ns       commitment-n    182.085018
abs     nmod+n+n        pledge-n        149.927391
abs     nmod+n+ns       reagent-n       142.347358
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r -n '/-n\t[0-9.]*$/{s/(\S+)\t(.*)-([^-]+-\S+)\t(.*)/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4/p}' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
abs nmod+n+n    commitment-n    349.200023
abs nmod+n+n-a  commitment-n    333.306429
abs nmod+n+ns   commitment-n    182.085018
abs nmod+n+n    pledge-n    149.927391
abs nmod+n+ns   reagent-n   142.347358
```